# Why can two Java processes bind to the same socket in macOS?

Tags: java, macos, sockets, networking, serversocket

I have some Java code that is generating a socket binding. It's hard to provide a minimal example as this is part of a web framework, but it effectively does this check at some point.

```java
  private static boolean portInUse(int port) {
    // try to bind to this port, if it succeeds the port is not in use
    try (ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
      socket.setReuseAddress(true);
      return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

I can see that if I run two distinct Java processes with the same port, they both fall into the first conditional and return `false`, thus both are able to bind to the same port. I've read through [some related socket questions and explanations like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/how-do-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-differ), but they seem to make it sound like this shouldn't be possible with the options I've specified. Looking at the implementation of `setReuseAddress` it only seems to set `SO_REUSEADDR` on the socket.

I can see one process ends up with a socket like `ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=56674]` in a debugger. If I run something like `sudo lsof -n -i | grep -e LISTEN -e ESTABLISHED | grep 56674` I can see two processes binding to the same port:

```
java      68863    natdempk 1256u  IPv4 0xbbac93fff9a6e677      0t0  TCP *:56674 (LISTEN)
java      68998    natdempk  985u  IPv6 0xbbac93fff2f84daf      0t0  TCP *:56674 (LISTEN)
```

I can also see some other projects like gRPC and Node mention this behavior as being observed with their servers in issue trackers, but they never explain why this is possible. **How can distinct processes bind to the same socket on macOS?**

I am running macOS 11.6.3 (20G415) if that is at all helpful. Happy to provide more debug info as well if anyone has anything I should add here.

Comment: Calling `socket.setReuseAddress(true)` *after* you've bound the socket is pointless. You should create it unbound, then call `setReuseAddress()`, then bind it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are not binding to the same port. One is binding to TCP on top of IPv6, the other is binding to TCP on top of IPv4.

To expand on the Java details a bit: `new ServerSocket(port)` in Java uses `InetAddress.anyLocalAddress()` because no `InetAddress` was passed in. `InetAddress.anyLocalAddress()` can return either an IPv4 or IPv6 address, which means this isn't guaranteed to be the same value to bind to across JVMs despite the same port being passed in.